# Can you force compilation despite errors

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to build and compile an Android applications even though it has errors and missing classes? (Assume the errors are in classes that won't be used during a round of testing for example).

Comment: Is it possible to put cat into the box if you do not have any cat?

Comment: you can put stub classes that looks like the missing ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Java, like many compiled environments, wants to compile the entire source tree on a build, certainly in the way Android does it.

However, presumably you could comment out the compile errors and references to missing classes, to get a clean compile, if those things are not needed at the moment.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure about Android apps, but I'm pretty sure when developing in Eclipse there's an option to "continue anyway" and run an application with errors.

Comment: @munyengm: Even if there is, I am betting that the Android tools will not necessarily like the output.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do that. You could temporarily comment incomplete code which is preventing compilation.